# Launch Screen Added from Info.plist is not working for SwiftUI 2.0 in iOS14.0

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios14, launchimage

I have added Launch Screen Image as well as background color for launch screen from info.plist which is available in SwiftUI 2.0 or iOS 14. But My Launch Image or the background color does not show while launching the app in simulator iphone 12 max pro.

I have checked everything in my assets file and also matched the image name and background color name that I have provided to the info.plist but nothing works.

Here is what I have done in info.plist:
[image]

Assets name in my assets folder:

[image]

While running the app in simulator it does not show the black background color or the image for launch screen it just shows a white background for a few seconds then takes to the app main view.

[image]

Comment: I believe we can just lunch Color! Have you tried your app in other simulator than iphone 12 max pro?

Comment: yes i have tried same issue..  :(

Comment: I had same issue I had quit the simulator and run again. Deleting the app did not work. Other thing could be the color that you have set for light and dark mode.

Answer (score 36):

I hit the same issue. Restarting the simulator made it start working for me.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.